# Render an object Property with Vue

Tags: html, vue.js

Excuse my Vue rookieness.
I have an object and its property {{oject.propery}}. The property contains a string ("error1,error2"). I need to render the string in my HTML in list form.

Instead of:
**You have the following errors: error1,erro2 ( {{}})**

I want: 
**You have the following errors:
 - Error1 
 - Error2**

I would assume split the string into an array and access the array[]

I can split the object into an array but {{oject.propery[0]}} isnt working.

What the easiest way to accomplish this with Vue.js?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the code you've attempted so far so that we can provide feedback. StackOverflow isn't a free coding service. As for the "easiest" or "best" method, this isn't the place to discuss that kind of question. You might instead want to look at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for assistance with improving an existing solution. I would encourage you to provide your existing code to receive an answer concerning a working solution, then head over to Code Review for a more in-depth look at how to improve your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{test(""error1,error2"")}} // 
computed: {
       test(str) {
          let strReplace = str.replace(",", " - ")
          return strReplace.replace(/,\s*([a-z])/g, function(d,e) { return ", "+e.toUpperCase() });
       }
}
```

Comment: Please refrain from just posting code.  Explaining your code  will prove more helpful to people.